# ios: Screenshot doesn't display mask Layer

Tags: objective-c, ios, screenshot, layer, mask

I have a view with a certain background color. I am masking this view with the following code:

```
UIView *colorableView = [[UIView* alloc] init];
colorableView.backgroundColor = someColor;

CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
maskLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:maskImageName].CGImage;

colorableView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Ok everything works fine there. The view gets masked, so some parts are transparent. Now I make a screenshot of this view:

```
CGRect frame = colorableView.frame;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size);

CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(someUninterestingCodeToGetACorrectPosition);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:c];
UIImage *screenShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return screenShotImage;
```

Taking a screenshot works (actually I display some other stuff above the view too and that gets displayed in the screenshot as well), but somehow, the mask is not recognized. Meaning what I get is a screenshot of a fully colored view (a rectangle) without the mask hiding some parts of it.

I guess ´UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`doesn't work with mask layers, so what can I do about it? I need to have a UIImage to display the screenshot in a mail.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this can be to use Quartz functions to clip the view (CGContextClip, I don't remember exactly, you'll have to dig a little bit into the documentation).
Hope this will help

Comment: Ok I´m using ´CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, maskImage)` inside drawRect method, now and it works for the screenshot. I only do this for the screenshot though, because you cant animate the colors (which I do sometimes) when overriding drawRect. One thing, do you know how to get a higher resolution mask, because I think the size of the rect limits the resolution of the mask. Because the original rect is pretty small, but the icon scales larger sometimes, and when I take the screenshot the mask resolution is much lower than the resolution of the mask of my original masking method.

Comment: Maybe because you are on retina display? If it's the case, you get the scale property [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] (not exactly sure about the syntax) and then you multiply your rect size by this value.

Comment: I´m working on Ipad2 so theres no retina display and the scale property returns 1. If I make the original view very large in Interface Builder the resolution of the mask is good. But the original view is as big as an icon and scales larger at some time. Then I make a screenshot and because the original rect was small, the resolution is low. I think I open another question for this.

Comment: Yes, it might be better with your new code. So that could help us to understand completely what you are explaining :)